# Xlsx to csv Running on Jenkins

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, jenkins

I've a bat script that converts the xlsx file to csv file conversion.
While I running the batch script from Command prompt I don't get any error it converts properly and the csv file is gets generated on the location.
But While I run the same bat script from my Jenkins I'm getting a error like

```
C:\Users\SVCT-WI-Jenkins\Desktop\Post_Patching\Mapping_Server\Excel2csv.vbs(9, 1) Microsoft Excel: Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\Users\SVCT-WI-Jenkins\Desktop\Post_Patching\Mapping_Server\WI_non_cluster_server_list.xlsx'. There are several possible reasons:

 The file name or path does not exist.
 The file is being used by another program.
 The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook
```

Is anyone have idea please help

My XLS2CSV.bat

```
    ::XLS2CSV.bat <xlsx_file> [csv_file_name]
REM @echo off&
setlocal
if "%~1"=="" echo(Excel file input missing...&goto:eof
if not exist "%~dp0excel2csv.vbs" (
(
echo Set objFSO = CreateObject^("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
echo src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName^(Wscript.Arguments.Item^(0^)^)
echo dest_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName^(WScript.Arguments.Item^(1^)^)
echo Dim oExcel
echo Set oExcel = CreateObject^("Excel.Application"^)
echo oExcel.DisplayAlerts = FALSE
echo oExcel.Interactive = FALSE
echo Dim oBook
echo Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open^(src_file, 0 , TRUE^)
echo Set objWorksheet = oExcel.Worksheets^(1^)
echo objWorksheet.Activate
echo oBook.SaveAs dest_file, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, TRUE
echo oBook.Close False
echo Set objWorksheet = Nothing
echo set oBook = Nothing
echo oExcel.Quit
echo set oExcel = Nothing
)>>"excel2csv.vbs"
)
if "%~2"=="" set "outfile=%~dpn1.csv" else set "Outfile=%~2"
"C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe" %~dp0Excel2csv.vbs "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\test\Post_Patching\Mapping_Server\%~1" "%Outfile%"
echo %errorlevel%
exit/b %errorlevel%
```

I called my batch script from Jenkins Build part.
Call my script `XLS2CSV.bat WI_non_cluster_server_list.xlsx`

Comment: What is the code for Excel2csv.vbs? Also, how is that script being called in the batch?

Comment: Edited my Question included my bat file

Comment: So based on that code it is saying that the Excel file is either missing or locked. You should at the very least test for the presence of the file in the vbscript.

Comment: I've tested the file is present in that location, as I said earlier while running the same batch file in my command line it has no errors and the csv file gets generated.

Comment: Look, all I can tell you is what the code tells me. The line that generates the error is trying to open the Excel file for reading. The error indicates that it can not do this because the file is either missing or locked. I'm just telling you that as a coding best practice if you have the ***script*** test for the presence of the file then you would know if the issue is the file missing or if it is the file being locked.

Comment: In the 3rd line of my script is checking whether the file exists or not
**if "%~1"=="" echo(Excel file input missing...&goto:eof**
this is the code

Comment: Ok, so assuming nothing happens in the interim then the file is locked.